# Vpn or proxy app for unblocking while using another vpn in android

Tags: android, vpn, proxy, censorship

My dorm's network uses a VPN to connect to university's internet network (without this VPN you can only access university's website and nothing more!).

And also I live in a country where there's internet censorship.

I've searched a lot but all applications I've faced are using VPN feature of android and android only let one VPN connection thus they are all useless to me.

Is there any application for Android that can bypass censorship for a certain app like youtube or chrome while I'm using university's VPN or manage to connect another VPN through my dorm's VPN?

Also, I have root access to my phone

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here. Though I have a feeling that this question is answered at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35255/the-safest-way-to-circumventing-irans-internet-censorship . One aside: If you are asking questions about circumventing a government's censorship program IMHO it's better not to do it under your real identity...

Comment: Hi, I've read that question and it's answer. my question is completely different. i want surf the web anonymously but i can't use VPN feature in android because i already have to use one to connect to the internet itself. and this is only needed for android because there are already apps like psiphon and freegate for windows that using proxy and not VPN.